# JS. Как "заспавнить" печеньку

Tags: javascript

Совершенно не могу понять как заспавнить печеньку(картинку) и затем убрать ее через пару секундa. В куки кликере при клике спавнятся печеньки которые затем падают вниз и исчезают, нужно что-то подобное.

Comment: А по-русски и как-то более развернуто можно?

Answer (score 1):

Если речь про установку и удаление Cookies, то можно сделать так. Для начала вот код функций установки и удаления Cookies.

Установка:

```
function set_cookie(name, value, exp_y, exp_m, exp_d, path, domain, secure) {
  var cookie_string = name + "=" + escape ( value );
  if (exp_y) {
    var expires = new Date ( exp_y, exp_m, exp_d );
    cookie_string += "; expires=" + expires.toGMTString();
  }
  if (path) cookie_string += "; path=" + escape ( path );
  if (domain) cookie_string += "; domain=" + escape ( domain );
  if (secure) cookie_string += "; secure";
  document.cookie = cookie_string;
}
```

Удаление:

```
function delete_cookie(cookie_name) {
  var cookie_date = new Date ( );  // Текущая дата и время
  cookie_date.setTime ( cookie_date.getTime() - 1 );
  document.cookie = cookie_name += "=; expires=" + cookie_date.toGMTString();
}
```

Далее устанавливаем и удаляем Cookies через пару секунд после установки:

```
set_cookie(cookie_name, cookie_value)
setTimeout(function() {
    function delete_cookie(cookie_name);
}, 2000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Если речь идет про "картинку", то:

HTML :

```
<img src="путь_к_картинке" id="#cookie">
```

CSS :

```
img { display:none };
```

JS:

```
//отображение картинки с id "cookie"
document.getElementById("cookie").style.display = "inline-block";
//через 2 секунды (2000 миллисекунд, можно изменить в setTimeout) она пропадет
setTimeout(function() { document.getElementById("cookie").style.display = "none" }, 2000);
```

Тот же код на Jquery:

```
$("#cookie").show();
setTimeout(function() { $("#cookie").hide(); }, 2000);
```

А вообще **нужно больше информации**.